# How do you convert P_lab into Sqrt(s) in scattering experiments?

Tags: experimental-physics, scattering

In some scattering experiments, sometimes the energy, sqrt(s) is reported. Sometimes momentum, p_lab is reported for the experiment. How do you convert from p_lab into sqrt(s)?

For example in this in Figure 72 and Figure 73 in this paper, or Table 2 https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.4984.pdf

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total energy in the lab is $E_{lab}=\sqrt{p_{lab}^2c^2+m_{beam}^2c^4}+m_{target}c^2$. Then $s=E_{lab}^2-p_{lab}^2c^2$.